# NullPointerException at Home.onCreate

Tags: android

I am trying to run a test program that allows a user to click a button and move to a different screen. I have the Home(First Activity) and Away(Second Activity) classes and a xml file specifying the layout for each. My source code is as follows:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Away.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});


    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

}
```

And Away.java

```
public class Away extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.away);
}
}
```

I get a NullPointerException in the DDMS trace

```
at Home.onCreate(line 17)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2627)
```

Anyone see anything in my code that may be causing this?

Comment: Oh sorry, it is create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findViewById()` traverses the view hierarchy set up when `setContentView()` inflates your layout.  You cannot retrieve a reference to a view in your XML before you have called `setContentView()`.  Change your `onCreate()` method in Home to look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //Call me first
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  Button create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
  create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Away.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
}
```

Otherwise, `findViewById()` will return null because there are no views in the tree...thus, a view with your requested id value doesn't exist.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the `findViewById` call can't find the actual thing you are looking for, it could return a `null` object and cause the call to `setOnClickListener` to throw an NPE.  Are you sure you've got the right ID (`R.id.create`) specified?

Comment: Yes, my button in the xml for Home is as follows <Button android:id="@+id/create"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:text="@string/createButton" />    I believe that should be correct